# Using Rails 4 to send email with images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, assets

Under the asset_host, `config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"` I am able to successfully preview emails to my specification without problems using:

`config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener`

However, my email is being sent without images (maybe assets) using:

`config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp`

What am I missing?

*Mailer view code*

```
<%= image_tag("#{image_path 'logo.png'}", :alt => "logo") %>

<p>Hi!</p>
...
```

Comment: Did you want the images as attachments? Or images inside the body of the email?

Comment: I want images inline with the body of the email.

Comment: How are you including the images in your email? Could I see some code?

Comment: I added some mailer view code.

Answer (score 0):

In your mailer file (eg: app/mailers/user_mailer.rb) call email_images before your mail() function

eg:

```
email_images # build images used in email
mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'New password request')

private

def email_images
    attachments.inline['logo.png'] = File.read('app/assets/images/mailer/logo.png')
end
```

In your mailer template use:

```
  <%= image_tag attachments['logo.png'].url -%>
```

Comment: Is this the same way to do it on production?

Comment: I am getting ``NoMethodError - undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass:`` using this. Has ``url`` been deprecated on Rails 4?